# Probabily: Permutation of words in a sample with replacement

Tags: probability

Form the six letters $A, B, C, D, E, F$ three letters are chosen at random with replacement. What is the probability that either the word BAD or CAD can be formed from the chosen letters.

a) $1/216$

b) $3/216$

c) $6/216$

d) $12/216$

My approach:

Possible outcomes $= 6 \times 6 \times 6 = 216$.

Favourable Outcome $ = 2 \times 3! = 12.$

Hence Probability $= 12/216$. I am getting d). So where am I making a mistake?

Reference: CSIR NET DEC 2015 Paper A Q.No. 50

**Edit:**  As it turns out I was checking the wrong answer key.  My solution is right.

Comment: Looks right ... are you sure the correct answer is c?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, you can check for yourself, CSIR NET DEC 2015 Part A Question 50.

Comment: Well, I still say it is d!

Comment: @BRam28 Sorry for the confusion, I rechecked it, as it turns out I was checking the wrong answer key. Mine (as well as yours) solution is right.

Comment: Aha!  I figured :) Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: wait, can you explain me how you get the favourable outcome?

Comment: why favourable outcome is equal to  2 × 3!